# Insert signature data into SQL Server in MVC 2 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, linq

I have working code that uses signature pad data to create and save a signature bmp image to a file location. My question is: how can I modify this code to insert the image into a SQL Server 2008 image field?

The following from my Controller obtains signature data from a signature tablet and creates a bmp image and saves it to a file location.

```
        [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
    public ActionResult SaveSignature2(IPrincipal principal) {
        int userId = ((ScoutIdentity)principal.Identity).UserId.Value;
        //Put user code to initialize the page here
        SIGPLUSLib.SigPlus sigObj = new SIGPLUSLib.SigPlus();
        sigObj.InitSigPlus();
        sigObj.AutoKeyStart();

        string visitorname = Request.Form["visitorname"];
        visitorname = visitorname.Replace(" ", ""); //combines the first name with last name with no spaces
        visitorname = visitorname.Trim();
        string thevrvIDstr = Request.Form["vrvID"];
        int thevrvID = Convert.ToInt32(thevrvIDstr);

        //use the same data to decrypt signature
        sigObj.AutoKeyData = Request.Form["SigText"];

        sigObj.AutoKeyFinish();
        sigObj.SigCompressionMode = 1;
        sigObj.EncryptionMode = 2;

        //Now, get sigstring from client
        //Sigstring can be stored in a database if 
        //a biometric signature is desired rather than an image
        sigObj.SigString = Request.Form["hidden"];

        if (sigObj.NumberOfTabletPoints() > 0) {
            sigObj.ImageFileFormat = 0;
            sigObj.ImageXSize = 500;
            sigObj.ImageYSize = 150;
            sigObj.ImagePenWidth = 8;
            sigObj.SetAntiAliasParameters(1, 600, 700);
            sigObj.JustifyX = 5;
            sigObj.JustifyY = 5;
            sigObj.JustifyMode = 5;
            long size;
            byte[] byteValue;
            sigObj.BitMapBufferWrite();
            size = sigObj.BitMapBufferSize();
            byteValue = new byte[size];
            byteValue = (byte[])sigObj.GetBitmapBufferBytes();
            sigObj.BitMapBufferClose();
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteValue);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            String path;
            path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            path = path + "/uploadFiles/Signatures/"+thevrvIDstr+".bmp";
            img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);



           ViewData["Result"] = ("Image saved successfully to " + path);
        }
        else {
            ViewData["Result"] = "signature has not been returned successfully!";
        }


        ViewData["Result"] = sigObj.SigString;
        //return RedirectToAction("vrSignIn");
        return View();
    }
```

I also have code elsewhere in my controller that gets an uploaded file and inserts it into the database. This code works OK.

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UploadTempFiles(string id, string u)
    {
        //this method temporarily stores files 
        string userIdString = Cryptographer.DecryptSymmetric("RijndaelManaged", SecurityImpl.UrlToBase64(u));
        int userId = Convert.ToInt32(userIdString);

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                int contentlength = file.ContentLength;
                byte[] b = new byte[contentlength];
                Stream s;
                s = file.InputStream;
                s.Read(b, 0, contentlength);
                VisitRequest.AddVisitorSignature(userId, b);
            }
        }

        return View("UploadFiles");
    }
```

I'm thinking that I can use some part of the second code to interrupt the image creation process in the first code and insert the image into the database INSTEAD of saving the image to a file location. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and I solved it:

1. Comment these three lines:

   ```
   //path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   //path = path + "/uploadFiles/Signatures/"+thevrvIDstr+".bmp";
   //img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
   ```
2. Convert image to String data (assumed that your variable 'strSignature' was declared before):

   ```
   strSignature = img.ToString();
   ```
3. Save it with your Stored Procedure.

Hope this help you!